# Angular - passing parameter from the Model to the Controller

Tags: angularjs

In my View, I want to display some text that is calculated with a function in my controller. I have tried inserting something like {{xlate('term1'}} inside my html. I noticed that the xlate function was called 4 times, but the parameter received was "undefined"
the code in my controller looks like:

```
$scope.xlate = function(term) {
    if (term == undefined) { return("") };
    if (userLang == "en") return langEn[term];
    if (userLang == "fr") return langFr[term];
    langEn = {
        name: "Name",
        officialDate: "Official Date",
        uploadDate: "Upload Date",
        selCat: "Select a Category",
        docFor: "Documents for ",
        loadingBoxTitle: "Working on it..",
        loadingBoxSubtitle: "Please wait while we get the documents..."
    };
    langFr = {
        name: "Nom",
        officialDate: "Date officielle",
        uploadDate: "Date de chargement",
        selCat: "Choisir une catégorie",
        docFor: "Documents pour ",
        loadingBoxTitle: "Recupération en cours..",
        loadingBoxSubtitle: "Merci d'attendre pendant qu'on l'on accède aux documents..."
    };
}
```

I want to reuse this xlate function many times in my HTML view to dynamically translate a few terms based on the $scope.userLang variable.

Thanks for helping me out here!

Answer (score 0):

A few things change this  `{{xlate('term1'}}` with  `{{xlate('term1')}}` and xlate is not always returning data:

```
$scope.xlate = function(term) {
    return "test";

}
```

Comment: You are right, I made a small typo! I also made the change to the code to insure it returns something in all cases now. Still the same behaviour. I was wondering if the syntax I used in my HTML was the right one...

Comment: set up a plunker because I can't see what you are doing. It should work but how can I tell without the code